# Laravel 5.4 update value from array in session

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I have a session variable that contains a variety of `json` objects and I want to be able to update these.

For example,

```
$userIndex = 123;
session()->get('app.users')[$userIndex]['phones']['landline'];
session()->get('app.users')[$userIndex]['phones']['mobile'];
```

How do I update the content value? How do I session `put` a new mobile number?

```
session()->get('app.users')[$userIndex]['phones']['mobile'] = '12345678';
```

Comment: `session()->replace('app.users')[$userIndex]['phones']['mobile'] = '12345678';`

Answer (score 1):

If you need to put new session variable for laravel, it's important to use "put". You need to change "get" with "put".

For example:

```
session()->put('app.users')[$userIndex]['phones']['mobile'] = 'YOUR MOBILE NUMBER';
```